# BL Manga where a depressed musician falls in love with a ghost in his apartment and starts playing for him again [bittersweet ending]

Tags: story-identification, manga

EDIT: I FOUND IT!!! It is called “Lonely to Organdy”. Finally!

so years ago I read a short and sweet BL (male x male) manga; it was a very short manga, maybe 6 to 10 chapters, black and white.

There was a boy who loved playing an instrument (probably violin if I remember correctly) but for some reason, he stopped. He was depressed and lonely but when he moved into his new apartment flat, he met a “ghost” boy who is supposedly dead, and he is the only one who can see and talk to the ghost. Over time he starts to play music for the ghost and gets encouraged to fight for his dreams again.

He gets very attached to the ghost too, there were R18 scenes of them being intimate, but as they became intimate the musician boy somehow got “tainted” so the ghost said they had to stop seeing/touching each other.

Overall it was a bittersweet story with a kind of a happy ending, I really remember the whole plot and scenes but not the name. I probably read it earlier than 2019, so it could be published anytime around 2014-2018, probably. Please send help if you know, it was so inspiring and I would really love to find it again!

Comment: BL being Boys Love?

Comment: Yes, BL stands for boys love, it could also be categorized as yaoi maybe. :’)

Comment: I think "yaoi" is a more specific sub-category of Boys Love. The former means it can have scenes of intercourse, whilst the latter is used to depict relationships without having it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I wanted to mention both of them since “yaoi” and “BL” are different categories in some manga reading sites. Unfortunately I don’t remember how it was categorized for this specific manga I am searching, it could be either!

Comment: Please post an answer below instead of editing your question to include the answer :-) Answering your own question is perfectly fine, if you were able to find the answer yourself. Ideally, you could also include some info about how you found it, and info about the story to verify that it fits your description, to make this post more useful to future searchers.

Answer (score 3):

Posting an answer in case gracie does not return. They can feel free to copy any or all of my answer, and I'd be glad to retract mine.

*[Lonely to Organdy](https://myanimelist.net/manga/100927/Lonely_to_Organdy)* (classified *Boys Love, Supernatural, Erotica* on Myanimelist.net)

[image: Front cover of Lonely to Organdy]

> Haruto Soma used to love music. Previously, he would write songs to play on the guitar and sing along to them. Haruto left his hometown to come to Tokyo and pursue a musical career, but his first live street performance was a major discouragement. Since then, he no longer experiences the same joy on the rare occasions he touches his instrument.
>
> Still living in Tokyo, Haruto is struck by a scooter one evening and taken to a hospital due to the alarming amount of blood at the accident site. Luckily, he is discharged a few days later, relatively unscathed; the only remaining ill-effect is a fuzzy feeling in his head.
>
> When Haruto returns home, he discovers a stranger lounging comfortably on the floor of his living area. His first thought is to wonder who this person is; the stranger, however, questions why Haruto suddenly notices him, because he wasn't able to see ghosts before!